# seeing http requests that ios app makes

Tags: ios, web-services, debugging, http

I'd like to see the request / responses that an iphone app makes.
I mostly work on web apps, and I can use firebug / fiddler to see them. But how can I see incoming/outgoing traffic of an iOS app, if im running it on my wireless?

Comment: If you run an Access Point on a 'normal' os (linux/windows) you can use wireshark to inspect the traffic...not easy but doable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Charles Web Proxy](http://charlesproxy.com) (and I believe Fiddler as well) allow connections from external hosts, when configured properly.  In Charles, you will need to make sure your iPhone is added to the Access Control List in Proxy -> Access Control Settings.

After that, you can simply set your iPhone's proxy to your computer's Charles or Fiddler instance.  In my case, my local desktop is at 192.168.10.1, thus my iPhone's proxy is set to:

```
192.168.10.1:8888
```

One problem, however, may be if you want to decrypt SSL traffic.  It may be difficult to get the iPhone to add Fiddler or Charles' certificate to the keychain.

Comment: FWIW, you can get iOS to trust Fiddler's certificates if you use the appropriate Certificate Maker; see http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp#ios.

Answer (score 2):

You could share your mac wireless to the iphone
And then use some tool, i personally use http://www.charlesproxy.com/ for these kind of issues

You could pick a tool from 
https://superuser.com/questions/99870/mac-wireshark-alternatives